# Parsing through xml page with c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I am new to xml and need to loop through a web page with xml similar to the example below. I need to store each element? of the xml into a variable so I can create a list with a row for each unique id. id: 101, Description: Auto, Name: Bon Bon, Street: 123 W Place St, State, etc. I believe the id would be an attribute? and the rest of the values are innerxml?

I have been searching for info on the web but haven't been able to accomplish much. Any help would be very appreciated as I am off to a slow start.

```
 <Master>
   <Dealers>
     <Dealer id="101">
       <Description>Auto</Description>
       <Name>Bon Bon Motors</Name>
       <Address>
         <Street>123 W Place St</Street>
         <City>Chicago</City>
         <State>IL</State>
         <Zip>82453</Zip>
       </Address>
       <PhoneNo>5451252222</PhoneNo>
     </Dealer> 
     <Dealer id-"102">
      ...
      ...
      ...
     </Dealer>
   </Dealers>
 </Master>


 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load("http://data.xml");
 XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
 List<SomeType> list1 = new List<SomeType>();
 if (root.HasAttribute("id"))
 {
      foreach (.... )
      { 
          int pk = root.Attributes["id"].Value;
          string description = ...
          string name ...

          list1.Add(pk);
          list1.Add(description);
          ....
      }
 }
```

Comment: `<Dealer id-"102">` has wrong sign. It should be `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something like what you're going for:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"..\..\input.xml");

        var container = doc.DocumentElement
            .GetElementsByTagName("Dealers")
            .OfType<XmlElement>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (container == null) return;

        var dealers = container
            .GetElementsByTagName("Dealer")
            .OfType<XmlElement>();

        foreach (var dealer in dealers)
        {
            var dealerId = dealer.GetAttribute("id");
            Console.Write(dealerId + " - ");

            var descrip = dealer.GetElementsByTagName("Description").OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (descrip != null)
                Console.WriteLine(descrip.InnerText);

            // etc...
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xml = @"<Master>
                    <Dealers>
                        <Dealer id=""101"">
                        <Description>Auto</Description>
                        <Name>Bon Bon Motors</Name>
                        <Address>
                            <Street>123 W Place St</Street>
                            <City>Chicago</City>
                            <State>IL</State>
                            <Zip>82453</Zip>
                        </Address>
                        <PhoneNo>5451252222</PhoneNo>
                        </Dealer> 
                        <Dealer id=""102"">
                        <Description>Auto</Description>
                        <Name>Bon Bon Motors</Name>
                        <Address>
                            <Street>123 W Place St</Street>
                            <City>Chicago</City>
                            <State>IL</State>
                            <Zip>82453</Zip>
                        </Address>
                        <PhoneNo>5451252222</PhoneNo>
                        </Dealer>
                    <Dealer id=""103"">
                        <Description>Auto</Description>
                        <Name>Bon Bon Motors</Name>
                        <Address>
                            <Street>123 W Place St</Street>
                            <City>Chicago</City>
                            <State>IL</State>
                            <Zip>82453</Zip>
                        </Address>
                        <PhoneNo>5451252222</PhoneNo>
                        </Dealer> 
                    </Dealers>
                    </Master>";

    var results = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root // Master
                           .Descendants("Dealer")
                           .Select(dealer => new
                               {
                                   Id = dealer.Attribute("id").Value,
                                   Description = dealer.Element("Description").Value,
                                   Name = dealer.Element("Name").Value,
                                   Street = String.Join(", ", dealer.Element("Address")
                                                                   .Elements() // Street, City, State, Zip
                                                                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                                                                   .ToArray())
                               }).ToList();

    results.ForEach(result => Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}; Description: {1}; Name: {2}; Address: {3}", 
                                            result.Id, result.Description, result.Name, result.Street));

    Console.Read();
}
```

Prints to the console:

```
Id: 101; Description: Auto; Name: Bon Bon Motors; Address: 123 W Place St, Chicago, IL, 82453   
Id: 102; Description: Auto; Name: Bon Bon Motors; Address: 123 W Place St, Chicago, IL, 82453
Id: 103; Description: Auto; Name: Bon Bon Motors; Address: 123 W Place St, Chicago, IL, 82453
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is more LINQified and simplified approach. I just wrote it and tested i            var

```
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\\TEMP\\test.xml");
        var nodesList = from xmlNode in xmlDocument.Descendants("Dealer")
                        select
                            new
                                {
                                    Id = xmlNode.Attribute("id").Value,
                                    Description = xmlNode.Descendants("Description").ElementAt(0).Value,
                                    Name = xmlNode.Descendants("Name").ElementAt(0).Value,
                                    Address = new
                                        {
                                            Street = xmlNode.Descendants("Address").Descendants("Street").ElementAt(0).Value,
                                            City = xmlNode.Descendants("Address").Descendants("City").ElementAt(0).Value,
                                            State = xmlNode.Descendants("Address").Descendants("State").ElementAt(0).Value,
                                            ZipCode = xmlNode.Descendants("Address").Descendants("Zip").ElementAt(0).Value
                                        },
                                    PhoneNumber = xmlNode.Descendants("PhoneNo").ElementAt(0).Value
                                }           
            ;

        foreach (var node in nodesList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Id);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the schema of the XML file, you can create classes and deserialize the XML into objects then you have max flexibility to process them.

In your example, you have three classes, Address, Dealer and Master. After deserialization, you will get a Master object containing a List property, and each Dealer object contains related information.